# hbase command to split and move region to different region server

Tags: hbase

I've a single region as I dont know key distribution. I want to gradually split the table so every region is split into 2. Using the following command, I can split the table regions:

```
split <namespace:table>
```

However, is there an easy move to automatically move the regions after split to other region servers for load balancing, instead of one region at a time. I've a cluster with 50 nodes.